# SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

im wondering which issue im getting when i try to remove a "Modulos" from the database. The exception it gives me tells me that the issue is caused by the foreign keys that are related in the hibernate files. When i try to remove data from a table that doesn't have any foreign keys there's no problem, and also i have more exceptions when i try to show all the data from the table.

Here i give the code:

**UfNotas.java**

```
package ufnotasORM;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import ufnotas.Profesores;
import ufnotas.Alumnos;
import ufnotas.Modulos;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import ufnotas.NewHibernateUtil;
/**
 *
 * @author Lluis
 */
public class UfNotas {
    
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        menuPrincipal();
    }
    
    public static void menuPrincipal(){
        
        ufnotasORM miGestor = new ufnotasORM();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Profesores> pro;
        List<Alumnos> al;
        
        int menu = 5;
        String nombre;
        String user;
        String pass;
        boolean check = false;
        
        do{
            
        System.out.println("1.- Insertar un nuevo profesor");
        System.out.println("2.- Eliminar profesor");
        System.out.println("3.- Validar la entrada de un Profesor");
        System.out.println("4.- Validar la entrada de un Alumno");
        System.out.println("0.- Salir");
        
        menu = sc.nextInt();
        
        switch(menu){
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Inserte el nombre del profesor :");
                nombre = sc.next();
                System.out.println("Inserte el nombre de usuario :");
                user = sc.next();
                System.out.println("Inserte el nuevo password :");
                pass = sc.next();
                Profesores p = new Profesores(nombre,user,pass);
                miGestor.insertarProfesor(p);
                System.out.println("Profesor insertado correctamente.");
            break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Escriba el nombre de usuario :");
                user = sc.next();
                pro = miGestor.mostrarProfesoresPorUsuario(user);
                if(user != null){
                    for(Profesores i : pro){
                        miGestor.borrarProfesor(i);
                    }
                }else{
                    System.out.println("No se puede dejar vacío el campo de usuario");
                }
            break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Escriba el nombre de usuario :");
                user = sc.next();
                System.out.println("Introduzca el password :");
                pass = sc.next();
                pro = miGestor.mostrarProfesoresPorUsuario(user);
                for(Profesores i : pro){
                    if(i.getNombreUsuario().equals(user) && i.getPass().equals(pass)){
                        check = true;
                    }else{
                        check = false;
                    }
                }
                
                if(check){
                    System.out.println("Bienvenido "+user+" !");
                    menuProfesor();
                }else{
                    System.out.println("El nombre de usuario o el password no se corresponde");
                }
            break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Escriba el nombre de usuario :");
                user = sc.next();
                System.out.println("Introduzca el password :");
                pass = sc.next();
                al = miGestor.mostrarAlumnosPorUsuario(user);
                for(Alumnos i : al){
                    if(i.getNombreUsuario().equals(user) && i.getPassword().equals(pass)){
                        check = true;
                    }else{
                        check = false;
                    }
                }
                
                if(check){
                    System.out.println("Se ha autentificado correctamente");
                }else{
                    System.out.println("El nombre de usuario o el password no se corresponde");
                }
            break;
        }
            
        }while(menu!=0);        
        
    }
    
    public static void menuProfesor(){
        
        ufnotasORM miGestor = new ufnotasORM();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Modulos> mod;
        List<Alumnos> al;
        
        int menu = 8;
        
        do{
            
            System.out.println("1.- Insertar módulo");
            System.out.println("2.- Listar TODOS los módulos");
            System.out.println("3.- Eliminar módulo");
            System.out.println("4.- Insertar alumno");
            System.out.println("5.- Listar TODOS los alumnos");
            System.out.println("6.- Listar alumnos por módulo");
            System.out.println("7.- Eliminar alumno");
            System.out.println("0.- Salir");
            
            menu = sc.nextInt();
            
            switch(menu){
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Inserte el nombre del módulo :");
                    String nom_modulo = sc.next();
                    if(nom_modulo != null){
                        Modulos m = new Modulos(nom_modulo);
                        miGestor.insertarModulo(m);
                        System.out.println("Modulo insertado correctamente");
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("No se puede dejar el nombre del modulo vacio");
                    }
                break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println(miGestor.mostrarModulos());
                break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Introduzca el nombre del modulo :");
                    String nomMod = sc.next();
                    mod = miGestor.mostrarModulosPorNombre(nomMod);
                    if(nomMod!=null){
                        for(Modulos m : mod){
                            miGestor.borrarModulo(m);
                        }
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("Debe introducir el nombre del modulo para eliminarlo");
                    }
                break;                       
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("Introduzca el nombre del alumno :");
                    String nombre = sc.next();
                    System.out.println("Introduzca el nombre de usuario del alumno :");
                    String nombreUsuario = sc.next();
                    System.out.println("Introduzca el password del usuario :");
                    String password = sc.next();
                    if(nombre != null && nombreUsuario != null && password != null){
                        Alumnos a = new Alumnos(nombre,nombreUsuario,password);
                        miGestor.insertarAlumno(a);
                        System.out.println("Se ha insertado el alumno correctamente");
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("No se puede dejar ningún campo vacío");
                    }
                break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.println(miGestor.mostrarAlumnos());
                break;
                case 6:
                    System.out.println("Introduzca el nombre del modulo :");
                    try{
                    String modulo = sc.next();
                    
                    if(!modulo.isEmpty()){
                        System.out.println(miGestor.mostrarAlumnosPorModulo(modulo));
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("Debe introducir un ID");
                    }
                    
                    }catch(InputMismatchException e){
                        System.out.println(e+" "+"Debe introducir un valor entero");
                    }
                break;
                case 7:
                    System.out.println("Introduzca el nombre de usuario del alumno :");
                    String user = sc.next();
                    al = miGestor.mostrarAlumnosPorUsuario(user);
                    if(user!=null){
                        for(Alumnos a : al){
                            miGestor.borrarAlumno(a);
                        }
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("No se puede dejar el nombre de usuario vacío");
                    }
                break;
            }
            
        }while(menu!=0);
        
    }
```

**ufnotasORM.java**

```
package ufnotasORM;

import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Projections;
import org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException;
import ufnotas.Alumnos;
import ufnotas.Profesores;
import ufnotas.Modulos;
import ufnotas.Historial;
import ufnotas.NewHibernateUtil;
import ufnotas.Notas;

/**
 *
 * @author Lluis
 */
public class ufnotasORM {
    
    private Session se;
    private Transaction tr;
    
    public ufnotasORM(){
        se = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    }
    
    public void insertarProfesor(Profesores p){
        try{
            tr = se.beginTransaction();
            se.save(p);
            tr.commit();
        } catch(ConstraintViolationException ex){
            tr.rollback();
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    
    public void borrarProfesor(Profesores p){
        tr = se.beginTransaction();
        se.delete(p);
        tr.commit();
    }
    
    public boolean validarProfesor(Profesores p){
        Profesores pro = (Profesores) se.get(Profesores.class, p.getId());
        return (pro != null);
    }
    
    public boolean validarAlumno(Alumnos a){
        Alumnos al = (Alumnos) se.get(Alumnos.class, a.getId());
        return (al != null);
    }
    
    public void insertarModulo(Modulos m){
        try{
            tr = se.beginTransaction();
            se.save(m);
            tr.commit();
        }catch(ConstraintViolationException ex){
            tr.rollback();
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    
    public List<Modulos> mostrarModulos(){
        String query = "SELECT m FROM Modulos m";
        Query q = se.createQuery(query);
        return q.list();
    }
    
    public void borrarModulo(Modulos m){
        tr = se.beginTransaction();
        se.delete(m);
        tr.commit();
    }
    
    public void insertarAlumno(Alumnos a){
        try{
            tr = se.beginTransaction();
            se.save(a);
            tr.commit();
        }catch(ConstraintViolationException ex){
            tr.rollback();
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    
    public List<Alumnos> mostrarAlumnos(){
        String query = "SELECT a FROM Alumnos a";
        Query q = se.createQuery(query);
        return q.list();
    }
    
    public List<Profesores> mostrarProfesoresPorUsuario(String p){
        String sql = "SELECT p FROM Profesores p WHERE p.nombreUsuario = :username";
        Query query = se.createQuery(sql);
        query.setParameter("username",p);
        return query.list();
    }
    
    public List<Modulos> mostrarModulosPorNombre(String m){
        String sql = "SELECT m FROM Modulos m WHERE m.nombre = :nombre";
        Query query = se.createQuery(sql);
        query.setParameter("nombre",m);
        return query.list();
    }
    
    public List<Modulos> mostrarAlumnosPorModulo(String modulo){
        String query = "SELECT a FROM Alumnos a JOIN a.notas n JOIN n.modulo m WHERE m.nombre = :modulo";
        Query q = se.createQuery(query);
        q.setParameter("modulo", modulo);
        return q.list();
    }
    
    public List<Alumnos> mostrarAlumnosPorUsuario(String a){
        String query = "SELECT a FROM Alumnos a WHERE a.nombreUsuario = :username";
        Query q = se.createQuery(query);
        q.setParameter("username", a);
        return q.list();
    }
    
    public long contarModulos(){
        long count = ((Long)se.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Modulos m").iterate().next());
        return count;
    }
    
    public void borrarAlumno(Alumnos a){
        tr = se.beginTransaction();
        se.delete(a);
        tr.commit();
    }
    
    
}
```

**Modulos.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="ufnotas.Modulos" table="modulos" optimistic-lock="version">
      <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
          <generator class="assigned" />
      </id>
      <property name="nombre" type="string">
          <column name="nombre" length="25" not-null="true" />
      </property>
      <set name="notas" table="notas" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="id_modulo" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="ufnotas.Notas" />
        </set>
  </class> 
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Modulos.java**

```
package ufnotas;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 *
 * @author Lluis
 */
public class Modulos implements java.io.Serializable{
    
    private int id; // Integer
    private String nombre;
    private Set<Notas> notas = new HashSet<>();
    
    public Modulos(){
        
    }
    
    public Modulos(String nombre){
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }


    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public Set getNotas() {
        return notas;
    }


    public void setNotas(Set notas) {
        this.notas = notas;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString(){
       String cadena;
       cadena = "ID : "+ this.id + " Nombre : "+ this.nombre;
       return cadena;
    }   
}
```

**Notaslinkia.sql**

```
--
-- Base de datos: `notaslinkia`
--
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `notaslinkia` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
USE `notaslinkia`;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `alumnos`
--

CREATE TABLE `alumnos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `nom_user` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(25) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `historial`
--

CREATE TABLE `historial` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tipo` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `detalle` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `modulos`
--

CREATE TABLE `modulos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(25) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `notas`
--

CREATE TABLE `notas` (
  `id_alumno` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_modulo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `notas` float NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `profesores`
--

CREATE TABLE `profesores` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `nom_user` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(25) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Índices para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Indices de la tabla `alumnos`
--
ALTER TABLE `alumnos`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `historial`
--
ALTER TABLE `historial`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `modulos`
--
ALTER TABLE `modulos`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `notas`
--
ALTER TABLE `notas`
  ADD KEY `id_alumno` (`id_alumno`),
  ADD KEY `id_modulo` (`id_modulo`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `profesores`
--
ALTER TABLE `profesores`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de las tablas volcadas
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `alumnos`
--
ALTER TABLE `alumnos`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `historial`
--
ALTER TABLE `historial`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `modulos`
--
ALTER TABLE `modulos`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `profesores`
--
ALTER TABLE `profesores`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

--
-- Restricciones para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `notas`
--
ALTER TABLE `notas`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `notas_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_alumno`) REFERENCES `alumnos` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `notas_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_modulo`) REFERENCES `modulos` (`id`);
COMMIT;
```

Any help will be grateful. Thank you.

EDIT: now im having this exception after insert cascade delete.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an exact answer, because I didn't parse all your Hibernate logic to see exactly what is happening.  However, it is fairly clear what would be causing this error.  The `notas` table has a foreign key which points to the `id` column of the `modulos` table.  Should your code attempt to delete a record in the `modulos` table which is still being referred to by one or more records in the `notas` table, you will see MySQL throw this error.  The reason is that the delete against the `modulos` table, if allowed, would result in one or more orphaned child records in the `notas` table.

To correct this error, you need to check your delete logic and make sure the above scenario is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

cascade="delete" which tells Hibernate to navigate the association and delete persistent instances when an object is passed to delete().

```
<set name="notas" table="notas" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade="delete">
```

I belive this should do the work